# How to generate LTPA token for WebSphere Liberty Profile

Tags: websphere, websphere-liberty, ltpa

Is there any utility that can be used to generate LTPA token keys for the WebSphere Liberty Profile. I am aware of the Liberty generating token by itself whenever we start the liberty server.

Also I have found a [utility](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ltpa) which helps one to generate LTPA for Domino based. But it doesn't work for WebSphere as we don't have a server secret.

My requirement is to generate the keys externally. Any help here is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Liberty automatically generates LTPA key and stores to `${server.output.dir}/resources/security/ltpa.keys`. See more details here - [Configuring LTPA in Liberty](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.doc/ae/twlp_sec_ltpa.html).

So if you want to generate your own just configure your own password in server.xml, like this:

```
<ltpa keysFileName="yourLTPAKeysFileName.keys" keysPassword="keysPassword" expiration="120" />
```

and it will generate keys using your password.

There is no standalone external tool. You can just use separate version of Liberty to create it and than share wherever you need.

Comment: Actually, in the latest Liberty Beta (August 2016) available here: https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/liberty-profile-beta/
a new standalone tool was introduced to create LTPA keys.  
It's part of the securityUtility, so you would do /wlp/bin/securityUtility createLTPAKeys